# calculate years to get a million from 1000€

Tags: python, calculation

I need to calculate how many years need to pass so 1000 euros become a million.

The program doesn't stops to million, it stops when a 1000 years pass

```
money=1000
interest=0.05
value=0
years=0
while True:
    value=(money*interest)+money
    money=value
    years=years+1
    if money==1E6:
        break
    elif years==1000:
        break
print('Money:{:1.2f}'.format(money))
print('Years:',years)`
```

Comment: Do you really expect the value to be exactly `1E6`? It might be better to ask `if money >= 1E6:`.

Comment: Thank you very much it works

Comment: also if you don't want it to stop at the 1000 years, remove the `elif years==1000: break` 2 lines

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```py
    money=1000
    interest=0.05
    value=0
    years=0
    while True:
        value=(money*interest)+money
        money=value
        years=years+1
        if money==1E6:
            break
    print('Money:{:1.2f}'.format(money))
    print('Years:',years)`
```

Comment: Please let this program run on your machine. After it finishes please come back and give us the result.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have tried that but it doesn't returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking whether the new money, after interest, is equal to a million euros, you should check whether it is equal or larger than a million euros. From `if money==1E6:` to `if money>=1E6:`

```
    money=1000
    interest=0.05
    value=0
    years=0
    while True:
        value=(money*interest)+money
        money=value
        years=years+1
        if money>=1E6: # I changed this line 
            break
        elif years==1000:
            break
    print('Money:{:1.2f}'.format(money))
    print('Years:',years)
```

The money variable will most likely never be equal to `1E6` so you need to check whether it will be bigger than that.